# Finding MIN nvarchar related to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, min

I have a table that contains a list of patient services and when they arrived to that service.  I want to be able to pull just the first service after the emergency department. Here is the table:

```
    Service                  DateTimeIn
    H EMERGENCY MEDICINE    2013-01-01 10:43:00.000
    H MEDICINE E            2013-01-06 23:43:00.000
    H MEDICINE E            2013-01-07 17:18:00.000
    H MEDICINE ICU          2013-01-01 15:38:00.000
    H MEDICINE ICU          2013-01-07 00:49:00.000
    H MEDICINE ICU          2013-01-08 04:36:00.000
```

When I use MIN(service) where service <>'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE' it pulls the service alphabetically, which isn't what I need.  I need the first service associated with the min time after the EMERGENCY MEDICINE service.  In this case it would be H MEDICINE ICU.  How should I arrange my query logic so that it pulls the min service based on the min datetimein?

Thank you

Comment: To increase your chances of getting the attention of users able to answer this question, you should [edit] it and add the applicable language [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). I would guess this is SQL, if so, please also add a tag to indicate the SQL DB you're using.

Comment: Can a patient have multiple "H EMERGENCY MEDICINE" entries?  If so, what results do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. If there is a valid reason that it needs to be deleted, flag the post for moderator attention, or use the contact link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter your query down to only the rows that occurred after the 'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE' entry, sort by `DateTimeIn`, and then grab the first one (`TOP 1`).  A pseudo-code solution would look similar to this:

```
-- Get all Emergency visits for a given patient
WITH CTE_EmergencyVisits AS (
SELECT DateTimeIn
    FROM   [ServicesTable]
    WHERE  Services = 'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE'
    AND    [PatientFilter]
)
SELECT SVC.Service,
       SVC.DateTimeIn
-- For each emergency visit...
FROM CTE_EmergencyVisits E
-- ... get the first service that occurred afterward
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
           Service,
           DateTimeIn
    FROM [ServicesTable] S
    WHERE S.[PatientIdentifier] = E.[PatientIdentifier]
    AND   S.DateTimeIn > E.DateTimeIn
    ORDER BY
          DateTimeIn ASC
) SVC
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it bugged me that the other answer doesn't return correct answer if 2 emergency records occur next to each other. The 1st record would incorrectly show the 2nd record instead of null since in that case there would not be a non-emergency record between the 2 emergencies. I stumbled on this looking up another query, so I  wanted to offer an update in case others stumbled on this.

The query below uses an `OUTER APPLY` instead of a `CROSS APPLY` and `ROW_NUMBER` to get the right next service.

```
DECLARE @S TABLE (
    [Service] NVARCHAR(40),
    [DateTimeIn] DATETIME,
    [PatientId] INT
)

INSERT @S
    SELECT 'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE', '2013-01-01 10:43:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H MEDICINE E', '2013-01-06 23:43:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H MEDICINE E', '2013-01-07 17:18:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H MEDICINE ICU', '2013-01-01 15:38:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE', '2013-01-07 1:41:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE', '2013-01-07 1:43:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H MEDICINE ICU', '2013-01-07 00:49:00.000', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H MEDICINE ICU', '2013-01-08 04:36:00.000', 1

DECLARE @PatientId INT = 1
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN S.Service = 'H EMERGENCY MEDICINE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsEmergency,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DateTimeIn ) AS RowNum
    FROM @S S
    WHERE S.PatientId = @PatientId
)
    SELECT
        E.Service,
        E.DateTimeIn,
        N.NextService,
        N.NextDateTimeIn
    FROM CTE E
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1
                Service AS NextService,
                DateTimeIn AS NextDateTimeIn
            FROM CTE
            WHERE IsEmergency = 0
                AND RowNum = E.RowNum + 1
        ) N
    WHERE IsEmergency = 1
```

This will then output:

```
Service                   DateTimeIn              NextService               NextDateTimeIn
------------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------- -----------------------
H EMERGENCY MEDICINE      2013-01-01 10:43:00.000 H MEDICINE ICU            2013-01-01 15:38:00.000
H EMERGENCY MEDICINE      2013-01-07 01:41:00.000 NULL                      NULL
H EMERGENCY MEDICINE      2013-01-07 01:43:00.000 H MEDICINE E              2013-01-07 17:18:00.000
```